# What happens when rain interrupts an ODI game in second innings before 20 overs and the chasing team is well ahead of D/L par score?

Tags: cricket, officiating, duckworth-lewis

In ODI cricket, minimum 20 overs to be bowled to use Duckworth–Lewis rule. But my question is even if chasing team scored the D/L 20 over par score target in just 10 or 15 overs, will it be mandatory to bat full 20 overs?

Example:
If team A batting first, scored 150 runs in 30 overs & all out (150/10 - 30 overs)
Target is 151 in 50 overs.

Team B batting second, scores 120 runs in 12 overs & lost 2 wickets. (120/2 - 12 overs)
Rain interrupts now. As per D/L method, revised D/L target would be 80 runs in 20 overs.

But play couldn't resume as rain continues till the end. But team B is well ahead of D/L par score. but didn't complete the 20 overs. Now what will be the result?

Will team B be declared the winner or the match is abandoned due to rain?

Answer (score 7):

My reading of the ICC regulations indicates that the above scenario would be a no-result.

The regulations are available [here](http://icc-live.s3.amazonaws.com/cms/media/about_docs/542bbed14ad2e-2%20_Standard_ODI_2014-15_Final_Oct_14.pdf).

The relevant sections are:

Section 12.4.2.B.iii states that a minimum of 20 overs in the second innings is required, subject to a result not being achieved earlier. In the example above, a result isn't achieved, as when the rain came they were chasing 151.

Section 27.7.2 says that a minimum of 20 overs is required in the second innings before applying the D/L par score. Hence, the D/L score above is irrelevant, and the match is declared a no-result

Answer (score 2):

In the given scenario, if the rain interrupts the game after 12 overs of the second innings and the play can't resume (i.e. not possible) after that, the game will be declared as **"no result"** sadly.

To get result of the match by D/L method, the target must be set by D/L method. To set the target by D/L method, all the conditions (e.g. no rain, fit ground etc) must allow to play the match further. If that happens (the conditions allows to resume the play) the target will be set by D/L. But still the team batting second do not win the match! They have to play at least one delivery to win the match.

In the match between [New Zealand and England in World Cup 2015](http://www.espncricinfo.com/icc-cricket-world-cup-2015/engine/match/656415.html?innings=2;view=commentary), someone asked if the rain interrupts the match (when NZ needed just 12 off 41 overs and the dinner break was taken) and no further play is possible will NZ win the match. In the reply they said:

> that happens only when the ground is deemed fit to play and a target
>   has been set for 20 overs. If there were to be rain now, and the
>   ground were not deemed to be fit to play, there would be no target in
>   20 overs (which I am sure New Zealand have crossed because they are
>   just one down), and there would be no result.